# How to call a method into a constructor in the same class and pass user input into this?

Tags: c#

I found few posts on here quite similar to my question. But that's not helping. I want to calculate area of a circle. Rather than passing value by myself I want to take user input hence I created a method called myValue(). Now I want to call that method or int _radius variable into a constructor. I am new to C# and like your advice on this:

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;

            namespace PracticeFor70_483Exam.Venkat
            {
                class Circle
                {
                    private readonly int Radius;

                    public static int MyValue()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter radius value: ");
                        return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }

                    float _PI = 3.141F;
                    public Circle()
                    {
                        Radius = myValue();
                        //this._radius = Radius; 
                    }
                    public float CalculateArea()
                    {
                        return this._PI * this.Radius * this.Radius;
                    }
                }
                class StaticAndInstanceClass
                {
                    public static void Main()
                    {
                        Circle c1 = new Circle(2);
                        float Area = c1.CalculateArea();
                        Console.WriteLine("The area is: {0}", Area);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to make `_radius` a member variable of the `Circle` class.

Comment: Please take more care formatting your code in future - it was all over the place before my edit. Use the preview before you post.

Comment: I highlighted method and constructor hence looking all over the place.

Comment: Creating _radius a member of Circle class is giving me error:    Console.WriteLine("Please enter radius value: ");
            int _radius = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); It is saying Console.WriteLine does not exist in the current context. @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the radius an instance field of the Circle class and modify the MyValue method.

```
public class Circle
{
    private readonly int Radius;

    public static int MyValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter radius value: ");
        return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public Circle()
    {
        Radius = MyValue();
    }

...

}
```

Please note that this is a very "bad idea" though, your circle class should represent a circle and nothing else. Giving it information about the console is strange to say the least. It violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) among other things.

Comment: I am getting error: "The name 'myValue' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: On what line? In the constructor?

Comment: Yes on the constructor.

Comment: Are you sure you have no spelling/casing errors. That error really shouldn't be there. Can you show your updated code?

Comment: see above. I made changes according to your post. Do you think there is a conflict between int and float?

Comment: You have a casing problem. There is no method called `myValue()` in your code above, there is one called `MyValue()` however. A general guideline is to always PascalCase method names and reserve camelCase for fields and local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in the given code:
1. `myValue()` instead of `MyValue()`. Since, it is case sensitive.
2. `Circle(2)` instead of `Circle()`. Since, it does not have a constructor that takes parameter.

Comment: Perfect Thank you both, that worked. A simple wrong case really cost you time.